# An endless loop in a desolate wasteland

Tags: wordplay, cipher, cryptic-clues

You check your position tracker.

*Back at the beginning.*

Slowly, once again, you begin taking steps and counting cracks in the sidewalk.

*One. Two. Three. Four. Five*

You look around. Pitch darkness. Nowhere to go except forward.

*Six. Seven. Eight. Nine. Ten.*

You pull a crumpled scroll out of your pocket. Perhaps today is the day you finally crack its code.

---

[image: left half of scroll]

---

*Eleven. Twelve. Thirteen. Fourteen. Fifteen.*

You reach into your other pocket and carefully pull out many small, rectangular scraps of scroll paper. Who perforates a scroll, anyways?

---

[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]
[image: scroll scrap]

---

*Sixteen. Seventeen. Eighteen. Nineteen. Twenty.*

These scraps used to be connected to your long scroll. The scroll and the position tracker were the only clues you had when you woke up here in this endless expanse.

*Twenty-one. Twenty-two. Twenty-three. Twenty-four. Twenty-five.*

You try to remember, but you can't. You don't know how long you've been here. You don't know how you got here. All you know is that now, you're here.

*Twenty-six. Twenty-seven. Twenty-eight. Twenty-nine. Thirty.*

Wherever here is. In this dark expanse, on this endless sidewalk, with nowhere else to go but forward.

*Thirty-one. Thirty-two. Thirty-three. Thirty-four. Thirty-five.*

You rummage in your back pocket and pull out another scroll, this one much smaller. The one clue you found as you explored this vast land of nothingness. The one clue that you're sure will point to a way out of this place.

---

[image: miniature scroll]

---

*Thirty-six. Thirty-seven. Thirty-eight. Thirty-nine. Forty.*

A way out of this place. A way home.

*Forty-one. Forty-two. Forty-three. Forty-four. Forty-five.*

You reach into your other back pocket and pull out four other small scroll pieces, these torn from the much smaller scroll. This strange land and its perforated scrolls.

---

[image: miniature scroll scrap]
[image: miniature scroll scrap]
[image: miniature scroll scrap]
[image: miniature scroll scrap]

---

*Forty-six. Forty-seven. Forty-eight. Forty-nine. Fifty.*

What drew you to separate the perforated pieces from the scrolls in the first place? How can you possibly get them back together?

*Fifty-one. Fifty-two. Fifty-three. Fifty-four. Fifty-five.*

Must have been the madness of this place. The unrelenting, unforgiving madness of this dark, desolate wasteland.

*Fifty-six. Fifty-seven. Fifty-eight. Fifty-nine. Sixty.*

Sixty. *Sixty*. The number echoes in your head. You stop and check your position tracker.

*Back at the beginning.*

Sixty sidewalk spaces. Just as the time before, and the time before that. Sixty sidewalk spaces in an endless loop.

And here you stand, at the beginning.

Slowly, once again, you begin taking steps and counting cracks in the sidewalk.

---

> ***Hint #1***
>
> You've been staring at the same text for what feels like forever, to no avail.
>
> *What does it mean? How can I even start deciphering it?*
>
> The mysterious symbols swirl and jumble in your brain. If only you had a **key** of some sort to start deciphering the text... unfortunately, it looks like the right half of the key has been torn off as well.
>
> *Hopefully the key is something easily recognizable. Perhaps even so easy that it can be identified with just the left half...*
>
> You spend a moment [closely studying the symbols you see,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gozwv.png) then get back to counting.

---

> ***Hint #2***
>
> Finally. *Finally.* After all this time, you've finally made some progress on this scroll. One by one, you're starting to piece together the fragments and get some answers.
>
> *Answers.* But that's all you have. **If only you had somewhere to fill them in...** A grid, perhaps...

Comment: I am *not* transcribing that. Could we have a text transcription (with arbitrary letter-symbol correspondence)?

Comment: @Deusovi and I have come to the agreement that tedious work isn't fun, but a text transcription would unfortunately bypass the first chunk of the puzzle. To suit both puzzle-solvers and myself, I'll provide the plaintext with arbitrary letter-symbol correspondence once someone has cracked the key, which can be done without ever looking at 99% of the rest of the puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers to the cryptic clues are:

> COMPOST, URETHRA, SHOUT, BACKFLIP, PERIOD, IDEAL, GAELIC, HENNA, ANGLO, BEFORE, CASTLE, VERBALLY, HOODIE, HARDY, EARTH, ORPHAN, GOVERNOR, MALLARD, ERST, INTERCOM, POSTURE, THRASH, OUTBACK, FLIPPER, IODIDE, ALGAE, LICHEN, NAAN, GLOBE, FORECAST, LEVER, BALLYHOO, DIEHARD, YEAR, THORP, HANGOVER, NORMAL, LARDER, STINTER

(Full details about the clues [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BakaRO-MljdNqlYjz_DSDne8ik_O-leI8gc1jmmh4-w/edit#gid=0), as well as some notes on some of the clues and failed extraction attempts.)

These can

> be formed into a loop of 120 letters so that the words go around the loop twice. (For instance, COMPOST is overlapped by INTERCOM and POSTURE.)
>  [image]
>  (Here, the first time through the loop has borders denoted by black bars; the second time around has borders denoted by color changes.)

Now, the other scraps

> are instructions for letters to look at. The second is the word number, and the first is the letter within it. They point to these letters:
>  [image]

Finally, we can get our answer by

> looking at the indicate letters and the letters in between the indicated ones. They spell out **STUCK FOREVER**.

Comment: (Thanks to several other puzzlers for helping solve the cryptic clues!)

Comment: Heh. Correct! Almost. The final message is...oh, I'd say about eight letters longer than "Trek". The anagram is just happenstance. :)

Comment: @BaileyM: How's this?

Comment: Top shelf, it is! Well done.

Comment: Just flipped through the spreadsheet - the error was in the transcription, not the clue. It should have transcribed to "beer". :)

Answer (score 8):

### Partial answer

Once you transcribe the symbols, you can form cryptic clues (as the tag suggests)

> most likely by putting one of the scraps after one of the lines in the scroll. This is suggested by the combination of the line "The quick brown fox jumps" and the scrap "over the lazy dog", which when put together form [the famous pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog).

It is possible that

> all the scraps are definitions and all the lines are wordplay, although this is still a guess at this point. **Edit: this turns out to be true**

#### Cryptic clues

Edit: See [@Deusovi's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48943/8949) for the complete solutions.

#### Transcriptions

**The scroll**

> The quick brown fox jumps
>  Sloppy mop is in charge
>  University's rather strange
>  Disgruntled host takes you
>  Support loud sass
>  Drowsier slob
>  I sell
>  Georgian parasites eradicated
>  Bird takes an about-face
>  Together with cast
>  Mixture of boor
>  Messy football shoes
>  Running back in stormy gorge
>  Veil? That is
>  Road parts the grass
>  Broken heart
>  Poor phantom's heart
>  Rule Oregon
>  All in ruin starts dying
>  Beleaguered rest
>  Devious corn mite
>  You are in a broken sauce
>  An hour in the garbage
>  Not possible? Not at first
>  Range of pages in pamphlet
>  One defective diode
>  Party ruined by eve's end
>  Undead English
>  North American article
>  Restless phantom
>  Cluster of trees carry about
>  Coming back to celebrate
>  Friend in hobo disguise
>  Did frantic hare in
>  Lust endlessly
>  Quiet follows Norse god
>  Dangle above
>  No cracked tooth
>  Fat Queen Elizabeth
>  Recolors poorly

**Scraps**

> communication system
>  spoken
>  village
>  compound
>  traditionalist
>  prediction
>  beat
>  seaweed
>  stance
>  somersault
>  fortress
>  uninhabited region
>  fertilizer
>  Scottish language
>  duck
>  era
>  tropical dye
>  propaganda
>  moss
>  soil
>  jacket
>  ball
>  over the lazy dog
>  robust
>  waif
>  previous
>  yell
>  natural
>  witch
>  long ago
>  white American
>  fluid duct
>  fin
>  sun cycle
>  cupboard
>  ruler
>  headache
>  restrictive person
>  Indian bread
>  perfect

**Clues**

> Sixth of one
>  Third of four
>  Fourth of ten
>  Third of seventeen
>
>  Eighth of thirty six
>  Fifth of twenty one
>  Fourth of thirty
>  First of twenty four

---

#### Figuring out the transcription

My first step was to look at

> the symbols which could stand on their own, and which therefore would correspond to the letters 'a' and 'i'.

Then, I looked at

> the two-letter words. I noticed that one symbol appeared after both 'a' and 'i' – this could be 'n', 's', or 't'. There was another two-letter word beginning with that symbol, and luckily for us, the only two-letter words beginning with 'n', 's', or 't' are "no", "so", and "to", forcing that second letter to be 'o'.

Continuing to look at

> the two-letter words, there was another which ended in an 'o', and which began with a letter that could come after 'a' or 'i'. This forced the letter to be 'n', 's', or 't' as well.

Now that

> we had two symbols out of 'n', 's', and 't', I looked at the three-letter words. There existed words which began with one and ended with the other, eliminating 's' as a possibility since there are no three-letter words beginning with 'n' or 't' and ending with 's'. This left us with two symbols for 'n' and 't'.

Turning to the clues,

> I noticed that the last word of the non-perforated section had to be "seventeen", based on the letter patterning, giving us a whole bunch of letters. Then came the realisation that the last word in each line was a number, since we could transcribe "one" and "ten" with our new knowledge. Likewise, the first word in each line was an ordinal number. Transcribing the clues gives us most of the letters.

Turning to the scroll itself,

> the first line read, "The _ui__ _rown _ox _u__s". Noticing that this matched the first half of "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", I filled in the appropriate letters. This gives us all the letters but one.

Then I set to transcribing the rest of the scroll.

> I made the realisation that some of the symbols corresponded to punctuation, accounting for the 29 rather than the 26 symbols. The second-last line gave the symbol for 'z', the last remaining letter.

This gives us the whole translation.

Comment: Wonderful! I'll almost certainly give you a bounty for the dirty work once the puzzle is solved in its entirety. :)